# sftp recursive put creates files from subdirectories in the root directory

Tags: sftp

I have a local directory structure like this on windows

```
- install_k3s.yaml
- files
  - registries.yaml
```

When I try to transfer this folder structure to a linux remote using the following sftp command

```
put -r *
```

All the files get created in the root directory on the remote so I end up with the following file structure

```
- install_k3s.yaml
- files
- registries.yaml
```

Notice that regisgtries.yaml is no longer in the files folder.

Even if if I manually create the files folder on the remote and then run `put -r *` registries.yaml is not put in the files folder, it still goes into the root.

I am getting around it for now by using scp, but as that is not secure we are being told to move to sftp, but this recursive issue seems like its going to be a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, because you must use the `lcd` command in SFTP to change the local working directory to the parent directory of the `files` folder before running the `put -r` command!

something like this :

```
lcd C:\path\to\parent\directory
```

and now, again like this:

```
put -r files
```

you can also use the `mput` command to transfer multiple files and directories while preserving their directory structure, like this:

```
mput -r *
```

good luck!